# Display MySQL Results in Different Sections of Page

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, while-loop

I have a MySQLi query that returns all of the "assets" assigned to an employee based on their EmployeeID. This works great. The problem I'm facing is in the presentation.

I have an HTML table that has two sections: 1 for Hardware and 1 for software. What I am hoping to avoid is having to perform separate lookups that generate separate result sets for each type of asset. The end result needs to display as follows:

[image]

I can build the table just fine. The result sets contains a field of `asset_type` but I've not had any luck figuring out the code to use to iterate through my single result set. Is this even possible? Can I pull just the hardware assets from the result set with a while? Perhaps a

`while($result['asset_type'] == "hardware"){
    echo ""; // table row code
}`

And then repeat the same thing later in my table code for `asset_type` software?

**UPDATE 1**
The code I've thought might work so far, but isn't doing anything, is

```
// SQL query
        $q = "SELECT * FROM `assets_table` WHERE `emp_id` = '".$emp_id."'";
        $r = mysqli_query($connect, $q);
        $total_assets = mysqli_num_rows($r);

        while($r){
            if($r['category'] = "hardware"){
                echo $r['asset_name']." - ".$r['hw_make']." ".$r['hw_model'];
            }
        }
```

Comment: how/where does the asset info come from?  if it's a db, can't you just do something like `select type, * from assets where user=$id order by type, name`?

Comment: It comes from a MySQLi database. If I order them that still doesn't let me place them in the table where I need them to. There are sectional breaks in the table. Iterating through an ordered result set won't account for that.

Comment: no such thing as a "mysqli" database. mysqli is an interface to a mysql database.

Comment: That's what I meant.

Comment: can you show us the PHP code you are using so far including your query?

Comment: See UPDATE 1 in my modified OP

Comment: why don't you just $q = "SELECT * FROM `assets_table` WHERE `emp_id` = '".$emp_id."' AND category='hardware'"; ?

Comment: Because then I have to do two queries... one for hardware and one for software. I'm trying to do this in a single query and then selectively display based on where the results need to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going ahead and breaking out the query into multiple result sets and dealing with them that way. It'd be awesome if you could have a while() with a WHERE statement when iterating through result sets / arrays.